# Is there anyway to force the charset in python email?

Tags: python-3.x, email

I am getting emails from china but they are all coming in as charset gb18030 and base64 encoding.  Is there a way to force charset to utf-8 and 7bit or 8bit.
My current code does not seem to work.

```
message = "name = {}\nsubject={}\norder data:\n{}".format(name,sub,data)
msg = EmailMessage()#MIMEMultipart()
msg['To'] = 'tome@gmail.com'
msg['From'] = 'fromyou@gmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = "Subject Line"
msg.set_content(message,subtype='html',charset='utf-8',cte='7bit')
server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

When I check the header its coming in with base64 and gb18030 charset.  It's a web form with no input form the user.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword arguments to `set_content` merely add a declaration to identify otherwise unidentified content, or override the header which Python would otherwise supply for you. To actually convert from one character set to another, you need to perform the conversion yourself.

If `data` is `bytes`, you can simply

```
decoded_data = data.decode('gb10830')
```

If not, then you really need to explain in more detail what exactly is in this encoding, maybe with a small sample.

You can't send `'utf-8'` with `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit`; this encoding is for purely 7-bit content (i.e. `us-ascii` or similar). Maybe look at the fugly `utf-7` encoding if you really need this (pro tip: you don't really).

Comment: Looking more at my issue I believe when the user replies to an email it is getting base64 encoding and gb10830 charset.  So I would have to do something with the script to decode.

Comment: If your question doesn't actually ask what you want it to ask, probably delete it and ask a new question about the *actual* problem you are trying to solve. I don't think I understand your comment, though. You can't affect what encoding the recipient's reply will use.